# Why does Spring report an error(can't rename...) when Check Out Maven Projects from SCM?

Tags: java, spring, git, maven, m2e

**Import -> Check out maven projects from SCM**

[image]

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: Thanks to Paul T. for your edit suggestions!

Comment: Whatever tool that is, try running as administrator.

Comment: Actually, I have tried this way(Running as administrator) but unluckily it didn't work. In fact, when the Spring is running, the folder even cannot be renamed manually!